# Problema con useEffect react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Intento ejecutar una consulta a una api cuando existe un cambio en el estado `consulta`, pero se ejecuta por primera vez sin que existe un cambio:

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';

import { Re } from '../helpers/help';


export const Formulario=()=>{

const [Valores,Setvalores]=useState({
pais:'',
ciudad:''
})


const [consultar,setconsulta]=useState(false)
const [temperatura,settemperatura]=useState({})
const handelvalor=(e)=>{

Setvalores({
    ...Valores,[e.target.name]:e.target.value
})

}



const Agregar=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault()
setconsulta(true)

}

useEffect(()=>{
    Re().then((resultadoapi)=>{settemperatura(resultadoapi)})}
    ,[consultar])

//...
```

Como veran cuando ejecuto el `onsubmit` cambio el estado del valor de `consulta` para que el useEffect ejecute el estado de consulta cuando cambie a `true`, pero se ejecuta solo por primera vez.

Comment: Que pasa si comentas el e.preventDefault()?

Comment: La primera vez que ejecutes la función `Agregar()`, el estado `consultar` pasa de ser `false` a ser `true`. Pero la segunda vez que llamas a esa misma función, ese estado va a intentar volver a setearse a `true` y como ya tenía ese valor de antes, entonces es muy probable que el `useEffect()` no detecte cambios y por lo tanto no vuelva a consumir la API.

Comment: Pero lo ejecuta por primera vez sin que cambie a true

Comment: ¿O sea que el estado `consultar` nunca cambia a `true`? Si es así entonces puede haber algún problema con la función `Agregar()`. Tal vez no se está ejecutando bien. ¿En qué momento la estás llamando?

Comment: si cambia a true, pero se ejecuta sin que yo accione la funcion agregar()

Comment: ose no espera el cambio de estado, se ejecuta por si solo

Comment: Ah, ya entiendo. Como ya te explicaron en la respuesta que te dieron, es normal que `useEffect()` se ejecute por sí mismo la primera vez. Pero, ¿cuál es el comportamiento que estás buscando? ¿que la consulta a la API se ejecute **solo** cuando cambia el estado `consultar`? Si por alguna razón forzosamente tendría que ser así, quizás podría servirte poner la consulta a la API dentro de la función `Agregar()` para que se ejecute solo si llamas a esa función. Aunque personalmente no creo que esa sea la mejor opción. Pienso que lo ideal sería que sigas el consejo de @g.4 .

Answer (score 2):

Una función `useEffect` **siempre sucederá** después de que el componente reactJS se haya renderizado, pintado o devuelto (render/re-render) en el navegador.

En la documentación de reactJS se puede leer lo siguiente:

> ¿Se ejecuta useEffect después de cada renderizado? ¡Sí! Por defecto se ejecuta después del primer renderizado y después de cada actualización.

Entonces, estamos seguros de que `useEffect` se va a ejecutar por lo menos una vez y que además, ReactJS va a retrasar la ejecución de esta función `useEffect` hasta que el componente se haya "renderizado".

Lo que se puede hacer en este caso es controlar el comportamiento de `useEffect`.

#### Lógica dentro de useEffect

En este caso se puede usar lógica, para controlar cuando se puede hacer la llamada `API`, manejando el estado de la bandera `consultar`, una vez que ReactJS haya "renderizado" el componente `Formulario`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(consultar){
        Re().then((resultadoapi)=>{settemperatura(resultadoapi)})
    } else {
        console.log("consultar es false, no API call")
    }
},[consultar]);
```

#### Devolver función Cleanup useEffect

Luego, se configura `useEffect` para regresar una [función de Cleanup](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup),
esta función se va a encargar de regresar el estado `consultar` a `false`, cada que el componente `Formuario` se desmonte.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(consultar){
        Re().then((resultadoapi)=>{settemperatura(resultadoapi)})
    } else {
        console.log("consultar es false, no API call")
    }
    // cleanup
    return () => setconsulta(false);
},[consultar]);
```

Como se mencionó anteriormente, `useEffect` se dispara siempre, por lo menos una vez;

Ahora bien, en este caso en particular para que `useEffect` se dispare en posteriores re-renders, el estado `consultar` debe cambiar su valor, pues esta listado en las dependencias del efecto.

Si no se regresa la bandera `consultar` a `false`, su estado se quedará con el valor de `true` y por lo tanto, el efecto ya no se ejecutará en posteriores renderizados. Por eso la necesidad de usar la función cleanup.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.