# Funcion me devuelve 2 valores repetidos en React

Tags: reactjs, fetch, async

Estoy practicando usar fetch con async y await en React, consultando una API publica de Rick and morty, pero al momento de mostrar los valores me los muestra 2 veces por consola (En la vista aun no muestro nada)

```js
import React from 'react'

const ApiRickAndMorty = () => {

    const llamar = async () => {
        const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api";
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const data = await resp.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
    llamar()

    return (
            <div>
                <h1>Api Rick and Morty</h1>
            </div>
    )
}
export default ApiRickAndMorty
```

Intente cambiar la respueta de la funcion a un return y usar un console.log directamente de la llamada de la funcion, pero ahora me muestra en consola un: Promise pending

```js
import React from 'react'

const ApiRickAndMorty = () => {

    const llamar = async () => {

        const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api";
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const data = await resp.json();
        return data
    }
    console.log(llamar());

    return (
            <div>
                <h1>Api Rick and Morty</h1>
            </div>
    )
}
export default ApiRickAndMorty
```

Comment: Una función `async` regresa una promesa. Sugiero implementar [`useEffect`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/469521/101408) para la llamada API, también verificar [el ciclo de vida del componente React](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/374167/101408).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso pasa porque la función `llamar()` es asíncrona y, cuando actualiza el valor de la consulta, se ejecuta de nuevo, es por eso que te salen dos resultados. La solución más sencilla es añadir delante de la llamada de la función un await.

```js
import React from 'react'

const ApiRickAndMorty = async () => {

    const llamar = async () => {

        const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api";
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const data = await resp.json();
        return data
    }
    console.log(await llamar());
    // Con ese await obligas a la función a no pintar nada por consola 
    // hasta que no se ejecute por completo

    return (
            <div>
                <h1>Api Rick and Morty</h1>
            </div>
    )
}
export default ApiRickAndMorty
```