# Problema con estrategia de Google (Passport.js + MERN)

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, passport, google-oauth

Estoy haciendo junto a unos amigos un proyecto MERN sobre una app de películas e instalamos el paquete Passport para la autenticación de usuarios. Primero configuramos la estrategia local que funciona pero con mis compañeros decidimos ir más allá y también usar la estrategia de Google para que el usuario tenga la posibilidad de iniciar sesión en nuestra app usando un programa ajeno a nuestro código.

El problema al que no le encontramos solución tiene que ver con el logout. El login del usuario de Google funciona, el back obtiene los datos, se envían al front y el usuario es autenticado y se abre su sesión pero no hay forma de cerrarla. Una vez que apretamos el botón de cierre la función del logout se ejecuta perfectamente hasta que los componentes se vuelven a renderizar y los datos del usuario vuelven a establecerse. Todos creemos que la causa de este problema es un useEffect que se encuentra en nuestro componente Header, el cual recibe los datos del back mediante una función asincrónica llamada googleAuthentication y los setea en una variable de useState que contiene los datos del usuario, pero no sabemos como solucionarlo. Personalmente yo intenté con condicionales y dependencias en el useEffect pero no tuve buenos resultados.

Esta es nuestra estrategia de Google en config:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20')
const User = require('../models/User')
const passport = require('passport')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

function generatePassword() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'); // genera contraseña aleatoria, modulo que viene de node JS "CRYPTO"
}

module.exports.googleStrategy = async function(passport) {passport.use("google",
  new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback",
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
  },
  
  async function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    let userGoogle = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

    if (!userGoogle) {
      userGoogle = new User({
        googleId: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        password: generatePassword(),
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        profiles: [{ image: profile.photos[0].value, name: profile.name.givenName, myList: [] }]
      });
      
      await userGoogle.save();
    }

    return cb(null, userGoogle);
  }
  ))}
```

Nuestras rutas de Google establecidas:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const passport =  require ('passport')


router.get('/login/success', (req,res)=>{
    if (req.user){
        res.status(200).json({
            message:"Successfully loged in",
            user:req.user,
            error:false
        })
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({error:true , message:"User not authenticated"})
    }
})

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope : ['profile', 'email']}))

router.get('/google/callback',
 passport.authenticate('google', 
  { successRedirect:'http://localhost:3000/',
    failureRedirect: '/signin' }), 
);


module.exports = router
```

Y por último el componente que contiene al usuario. Aclaro también que el useState que contiene al usuario (const [user, setUser]) está originalmente en el archivo padre (App.jsx) y llega a este header gracias a un useContext.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext , useEffect} from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../UserContext';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import '../sketch.css'
import {NavLink, Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

function Header(){
  const {user , setUser} = useContext(UserContext)
  const navigate = useNavigate()
   // Al cargar el componente, verificamos si la información del usuario está en localStorage
   useEffect(() => {
    const savedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (savedUser) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(savedUser));
    }
  }, []);

  // Cuando el usuario cambia, lo guardamos en localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
  }, []);

  // Busca los datos de autenticacion de Google
useEffect(() => {
  async function googleAuthentication() {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/auth/login/success', { withCredentials: true });
    console.log(response)
    if (response.data.user && response.data.error === false) {
      setUser(response.data.user);
    }
  }
  googleAuthentication();
}, []);

  const LogOut = async () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('user')
    const data = await axios.request({method:"GET",url:"http://localhost:3001/logout"})
    console.log(data)
    setUser(false) //importante setear a user en falso así se borra el usuario en el front
    navigate("/")
  }

  return (
    <>
    <header class="d-flex justify-content-between py-4 px-5">
            <img src="/logo.png" alt="Movies Hub" class="logo"/>
            <div class="header-content d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
             <NavBar></NavBar>
                <a href="#search"><button class="btn-search"><i class="bi bi-search px-5"></i></button></a>
                { user ?(
                  <div className='dropdown'>
                    <button className='btn px-4 colorButton ms-2 dropdown-toggle' type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{user.name}</button>
                    <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <Link to="/profiles" className="dropdown-item hoverModal">Profiles</Link>
                      <Link className="dropdown-item hoverModal" onClick={LogOut}>Logout</Link>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                ) : ( <NavLink to="/signin"><button class="btn px-4 colorButton ms-2">Sign in</button></NavLink>
                )} 
            </div>
        </header>
  
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Muchas gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que implementando la función `cleanUp` de `useEffect` resuelva el problema, la lógica del `logout` debe ir dentro de la función `cleanup`, algo así:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const connection = googleConnection();
      connection.connect();
      //funcion cleanUp
      return () => {
        connection.disconnect();
      };
  }, []);
```

Esta función cleanUp corre cuando el componente se ha desmontado, mas [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469452/problema-con-useeffect-react/469521#469521)